# how to write migrations to add foreignkey to already existing tables in sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have this already created two tables called **User** and **Profile**.

This is how my model for User looks like..

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const db = require("../db");

const User = db.define("User", {
  id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    autoIncrement: true,
  },
  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    unique: true,
   validator: {
      isEmail: true,
    },
  },
});

module.exports = User;
```

and model for **Profile** looks like..

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");
const User = require("./User");

const db = require("../db");

const Profile = db.define("Profile", {
  image: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
  },

  description: {
    type: Sequelize.TEXT,
  },

});


module.exports = Profile;
```

Now I want to define a one-to-one relationship between **User** and **Profile** such that user will recieve a profileId column.
so i am defining it like this

```
Profile.hasOne(User, {
  foreignKey: {
    allowNull: false,
  },
});
User.belongsTo(Profile);
```

Now i am not able to figure out **how to write migrations for the newly  added foreign key**
can anyone help me please..
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. for someone who is confused like me here is the answer

since the User table already exists, **migrations** **for the foreignkey will look like this**

```
module.exports = {
  async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return await queryInterface.addColumn("Users", "ProfileId", {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: "Profiles",
        key: "id",
      },
    });
  },

  async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return await queryInterface.removeColumn("Users", "ProfileId", {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: "Profiles",
        key: "id",
      },
    });
  },
};
```

the **Users** in addColumn and removeColumn is the name of the table in which foreignkey was added.

the **ProfileId** is the name for foreignkey which you would have specified in hasOne.

hope this helps..